# How can I dual boot ubuntu and encrypt it’s ssd and hdd partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, encryption

first of all I apologize for my broken english as it might make this text more difficult to understand.

I have a pc with windows 10 installed on a 250GB ssd, I also use a 1TB hdd to save files and install some programs.

I would like to dual boot ubuntu on my ssd and also assign it a partition of my hdd to store files. The thing is that I want to isolate ubuntu from windows as much as possible and I read that this could be achieved by encrypting ubuntu (both the ssd and hdd partitions).

My questions is:

How can I do all this?, when I search for dual booting or encrypt one OS I only find videos and blogs explaining how to do it if you have just one drive and not two as in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not so sure how you’d go about doing this in one go, but I’ve done something similar on my dual-boot machine with several attached drives, and this can be summarized as:

1. Select the encrypt option for your OS partition during OS installation. This takes care of one part.
2. Use Vera Crypt (a multi-platform freeware) post OS installation to encrypt your HDD drive with a custom key. Here’s the link: https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html

NOTE: the drives/partitions might still appear upon booting into other OS within the same system, but provided they were encrypted, they will not be accessible.